# Integrate Moxiemanager with Mosaico

Tags: javascript, node.js, moxiemanager, mosaico

I have Mosaico setup and moxiemanager is under the root directory.
I can't find clear instructions on how to integrate it with Mosaico.

I do find clear instructions on how to integrate it with Tinymce.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this but just a few links that could be helpful :

- seems to be the line where the icon for editing image is displayed : https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico/blob/master/src/tmpl/img-wysiwyg.tmpl.html#L17
- the function selectImage called by the link is defined here : https://github.com/voidlabs/mosaico/blob/master/src/js/viewmodel.js#L480 so i guess you will have to change it so that is calls moxiemanager